# Wie werden Lehnwörter aus dem Französischen ausgesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation

z. B. Chance, Engagement

Werden sie wie im Französischen ausgesprochen oder gibt es eine deutsche Aussprache?

Comment: Einer meiner Lehrer in der Schule hat Brange "Brang-sche" ausgesprochen. Es hat mich ziemlich genervt, aber ich vermute dies ist akzeptabel.

Comment: Da irgendwer diese Frage als zu weitgefasst schließen möchte: Ja, die Frage ist wörtlich genommen unbeantwortbar, da kein festes Schema existiert. Wenn man aber nicht alles wortwörtlich nimmt, sollte klar werden, dass der Fragesteller nicht völlig unberechtigterweise angenommen hat, dass es so ein Schema gibt. Insofern kann diese Frage durchaus durch das Widerlegen eben dieser Annahme klar beantwortet werden – was auch alle Antworten auf die ein oder andere Weise tun.

Comment: Die Frage nach Ausspracheregeln ist zu komisch, angesichts der Mundartenvielfalt, die wir im Deutschen haben.

Comment: @polemon: War hier "Branche" gemeint?

Answer (score 6):

German and French differ in their phoneme inventories. In particular the [French nasal vowel variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Nasal_vowels) (as in *sang, en, quinze, bon* or *brun)* are missing in German¹ and they are not part of the native speaker’s sound inventory.

Thus the “correct” pronunciation is the original French one, but German native speakers may only be able to vocalize these sounds to a certain degree (or with a disproportionate effort). Common realisations include dropping the nasal feature (e.g., ʃãˈtal → ʃanˈtal for *[Chantal](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chantal))* and shifting the nasal feature to the following *n* sound, which may be nasal in German (e.g., bɔ̃ː→ bɔŋ for *[Bon](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bon)).* The vowel may become rounded in the course of this shift, too (e.g., ɑ̃ → ɔŋ for *[en](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/en#en_.28Franz.C3.B6sisch.29)* as in *en garde).*

---

¹ cf. [Monophthongs in German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_phonology#Monophthongs)

Answer (score 4):

Ich denke, es dürfte sich kein brauchbarer Satz an Regeln finden lassen, anhand dessen die Standardaussprache (geschweige denn die übliche Bandbreite) französischer Fremdwörter bestimmen lässt. Zur Illustration ein paar Beispiele, die im Französischen ähnlich, aber im Deutschen verschieden ausgesprochen werden:

- *Pinzette* kenne ich praktisch nur komplett »deutsch« ausgesprochen, also pɪnˈʦɛtə.
- *Toilette* ist ein Beispiel dafür, dass innerhalb eines Wortes der Grad der Originaltreue der Aussprache wechselt: Meiner Erfahrung nach wird der zweite Teil immer lɛtə, also »deutsch« ausgesprochen, beim ersten Teil habe ich schon twa, to̯a, to, tɔ und sogar tɔɪ̯ gehört, wobei to̯a vom Duden als Standardaussprache angesehen wird.
- In *Eau de Toilette* hingegen wird der zweite Teil von *Toilette* immer lɛt ausgesprochen, also z. B. ˈoː də twaˈlɛt oder ˈoː də to̯aˈlɛt.
- *Baguette* kenne ich nur »französisch«, also baˈɡɛt ausgesprochen.
- *Chance* habe ich schon als ʃãːs, ˈʃãːsə, ʃaŋs, ˈʃaŋsə und sogar ˈʃanʦə gehört.
- *Balance* hingegen habe ich nur als baˈlãːs oder baˈlaŋs gehört.

Generell vermute ich, dass folgende Aspekte die Aussprache beeinflussen:

- Wann wurde das Wort entlehnt? Und welche verschiedenen Rechtschreibparadigmata bezüglich der Schreibung französischer Fremdwörter hat das Wort durchlebt?
- Welches grammatikalische Geschlecht erhielt das Wort?
- Wie gebräuchlich ist und war das Wort in welchen Bildungskreisen?
- Wie stark weicht die Laut-Buchstaben-Zuordnung von der deutschen ab?
- Enthält das Wort Phoneme, die im Deutschen nicht üblich sind (siehe [Collapsars Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/10843/2594))?
- Birgt die Originalaussprache irgendwelche Probleme bei der Beugung?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is a general answer for this question.

I'd say like in French, but still with a different pronunciation. Whereat a French would pronounce it not like a German. But if someone knows French, that might be again a different situation. So it might depend on the speaker.

For instance leo.de gives

> [Chance](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Chance&searchLoc=1&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) and [Engagement](http://dict.leo.org/frde/index_de.html#/search=Engagement&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) (close to French)

but

> [en masse](http://dict.leo.org/frde/index_de.html#/search=en%20masse&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) (like in German)

The latter I never heard myself pronounced like that in public. Others give other pronunciation (e. g. pons). So, it probably differs, having several factors.

For a specific word / term it might possible to figure something.

Comment: The LEO pronunciations of *en masse*, *en bloc*, *en gros* are completely **wrong**. They appears to be computer generated. See [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/en_masse) for an appropriate pronunciation sample.

Comment: The 'correct' pronunciation is close to French. That said, there are lots of people mispronouncing these words, and if you watch German TV shows you may well witness `Chance` being pronounced close to `Schanze`. But sticking to the French pronunciation is safe and the speaker will be perceived as more educated than someone using a 'germanised' version.

Comment: The first pronunciation of *Chance* in Duden is [the French one](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chance).

Comment: Another interesting thing I observerved (in south-west Germany) is a pronunciation of French words that seems similar to the accent in southern France: "Gratin" -> "Grateng". Maybe also ["Grand" (in a Skat game)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Grand_Spiel_Skat): "Grang".

Comment: @MCL, ja dazu wäre es interessant, zu wissen, wie die Franzosen sprachen, die die Wörter nach Deutschland mitgebracht haben. Auch in Berlin reimt sich *Cousin* auf *Peng*.

Answer (score 1):

As a french native speaker working every day with german speaking people, French words are pronounced very differently from German speaking people as from French speaking people. Even if they are almost always able to pronounce the nasal vowels (*en*, *in*, *an*, etc.). The whole word is always different pronounced to my ears. Typically the first syllable is often the one which is accentuated, where the last one (or no one) is accentuated by French speakers.

Because of this difference, I force myself to pronounce differently French words when I speak German, to avoid any understanding problems with people not used to the French pronunciation.