# The loanwords of which languages are to be faithfully pronounced when speaking German?

Tags: pronunciation, loanword, phonetics

I have the impression that – unlike English (where you say *Euler* as *Yuler*, or better yet, *bruschetta* as [/brʊˈʃɛtə/]), European Spanish (where one pronounces *Wi-Fi* as *guifi)* or French (*Bounty* as *buntý)* and, for sure, unlike some other tongues – German tends to respect the original phonetics of foreign languages. At least, speakers of German try a very good approximation of it. So far, I’ve always heard nicely pronounced Gallicisms with good nasal sounds. The ending consonants of French words are also correctly omitted, when they should. If people don’t know how to say it in French, they “always” know how to pronounce independent loanwords. Needless to say English pronunciation is respected (though [not always](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/deutsche-aussprache-von-boston), as I’ve been just pointed out).

But, one easily finds counter-examples.

1. **Russian**. So, I thought, it would be the same situation with Russian. As you might know, transliteration from Cyrillic to Roman doesnt take into account the irregularities in the pronunciation. For example for the vowel *o* becomes the radically different [ʌ] (where the latter is the IPA sign). Once I pronounced *Dostojewski* as in Russian in a German conversation. I wasn’t well understood and got even ”corrected”:

   > Kumpel: *Wer? Ach Dostojewski, meinst du!* (all *o* as the *o* in *Gott;* i.e. false)
2. **Dutch**. Once I heard somebody saying *Gouda* as it reads in German. The sounds weren’t approximated (only *da* coincides with the original Dutch) and I didn’t hear it in the supermarket (although the subject was, indeed, cheese).

This makes me suppose that there is a list of languages to be faithfully pronounced. Nobody would speak all languages, but sometimes one would care about the original sound and I don’t know if it’s worth the effort of looking for it or even counter-productive.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: @Em1 Um es etwas plakativ zusammenzufassen: er wundert sich, warum die Deutschen z.B. den Vornamen von Präsident Mitterand i.d.R. korrekt aussprechen, den von Präsident Jelzin hingegen so, als wäre er ein bekannter deutscher Tennisspieler.

Comment: Ich wage zu behaupten, dass wir es bei allen Namen/Wörter versuchen, nur bei Russisch, Japanisch, Chinesisch versagen wir, weil wir es einfach nicht aussprechen können.

Comment: @c.p. Ich glaube, es hängt alles von Umfeld und Vorbildung ab. Deutschschweizer betonen ihre Gallizismen konsequent auf der ersten Silbe, mit "korrekt" ausgesprochenen Varianten von Valencia oder Giro(-Konto) dürftest Du Erstaunen oder gar Unverständnis ernten, und was das Englische angeht, siehe z.B. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/deutsche-aussprache-von-boston Zur Vorbildung gehören insbesondere die erlernten Fremdsprachen, was ich als Hauptgrund dafür ausmachen würde, warum es mit Englisch oder Französisch besser klappt als mit Russisch, Chinesisch, Ungarisch...

Comment: (Großartige Frage!) Ich habe das Gefühl, es hat nichts mit der Bildung der Sprecher zu tun. Mir fällt sogar bei der Tagesschau auf, dass man sich bei z. B. spanischen Namen wenig Mühe gibt ("Barselona", auch wenn die Sprecher das englische "th" beherrschen, spa. "d" wird wie deutsches "d" ausgesprochen, also "Madritt", etc.); Griechisch wird eher wie Altgriechisch ausgesprochen, außer die Transkription gibt Hinweise (also "Warufakis" statt "Baru..."); bei Italienisch gibt sich die Tagesschau mehr Mühe ("Giglio" wurde weitgehend korrekt ausgesprochen); bei z. B. frz. "Hollande" auch.

Comment: Das Problem bei Niederländisch wird wohl eher sein, dass es vom Schriftbild *zu nahe* am Deutschen liegt. "Enschede" sieht z. B. wie ein deutscher Städtename aus; jemand ohne niederländische Kenntnisse wird nie auf die Idee kommen, das "sch" anders als ein deutsches "sch" auszusprechen.

Comment: @Chris: Ich stimme dir bezüglich Niederländisch zu; ich kenne im Deutschen die Aussprache des genannten Wortes "Gouda" eigentlich nur als "gau-dah", und das leuchtete in - "ou" gibt's im Deutschen nicht, also kann es gut sein, dass hier eine Orientierung am Original eintritt; "g" gibt es aber bereits im Deutschen, deshalb kommt, ähnlich wie bei deinem Beispiel, niemand auf die Idee, das "g" anders als im Deutschen auszusprechen.

Comment: @Chris: Dessen ungeachtet hat es *manchmal* durchaus mit der Bildung der Sprecher zu tun. Ich habe schon vereinzelt gehört, wie Leute allen Ernstes eine *Soße*, die mit der ans Französische angelehnten Schreibweise *Sauce* geschrieben war, als "sau-käh" bezeichnet haben. Und was *Barcelona* angeht: "Barselona" stört mich eher wenig (in der Gemeinschaft der spanischen Muttersprachler auf dieser Welt gibt es immerhin sehr unterschiedlich starke Ausprägungen des Lispelns), aber die meisten Deutschen sagen dazu leider "Bartselona".

Comment: Related: [How should one pronounce “Denglisch” words when one is a native English speaker?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/11239/2594), [Wie werden Lehnwörter aus dem Französischen ausgesprochen?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10800/2594).

Comment: Re your “Euler” example: I’m sure that English-speakers meeting it for the first time may often say *yuler*, but among groups who mention Euler regularly, it is always pronounced approximately correctly in my experience (as what an English-speaker might spell as *oiler*).  Some examples where the incorrect pronunciation has become more established would be *chaise-longue* (which in the US has become *chaise-lounge*), *Fuchsia* (pronounced roughly *fyusha*), and *bruschetta*, in which the *sch* is usually pronounced as if would be in German, not the *sk* it would be in Italian.

Comment: Im Radio und Fernsehen in Deutschland werden schwedische Personen- und Ortsnamen so gut wie immer falsch ausgesprochen; Beispiele sind Wilander, Göteborg, Kerstin, Kjell, Linköping, Sjögren.

Comment: Meines Wissens gibt es in fast allen Sprachen eigene Wörter für fremde Orte. Der Deutsche sagt zurecht Paris statt Pari', und der Ami sagt Päriss - auch zurecht.

Comment: @Martin I nearly fell over when I first got corrected on saying Köttbullar in the presence of a Swedish expatriate.

Comment: @Em1 my parents, who had to endure 7 years of obligatory Russian in school in the GDR, also do the Russian loanwords wrong. Boris Jelzin as in Boris Becker, for example.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu That is another good example! As far as food it concerned, though, rather eat some other things in Sweden; that is my recommendation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pronunciation you heard for both *Dostojewski* and *Gouda* are the ones every German would reproduce.

I would blame school subjects, mostly. While everyone gets taught English and many people French, which also means that there is a critical mass of speakers of those languages that everyone will have heard the correct pronunciation, Russian and Dutch are hardly taught at school. Russian was taught a lot in the former GDR, but I have no idea if the East Germans are better at pronouncing Russian words.

If Dutch is taught at all, it will likely be close-ish to the Netherlands border and not systematically. Moreover, it looks so close to German, that nobody would think to pronounce it in a non-German way; the example given was *Enschede* (Germans use a *sh* sound for *sch*), but the *Schiphol* airport works equally.

The Portuguese word *maracujá,* imported to mean *passion fruit,* is also pronounced as if it were genuinely German *(j* as [j], stressed on the third syllable); the Spanish-derived *Vanille* ends in *-ille* or *-illje* here; and *Mezzosopran* is rendered with an unvoiced *tz* sound in *Mezzo.* Spanish is taught, but it’s usually third or voluntary language if at all. Same goes for Italian.

So basically, if the language isn’t English or French, the first general rule is to pronounce the word as if it were German. If a word is recognised to be from a specific language, sometimes language-specific pronounciation of uncommon letters is retained *(Cappuccino, Stracciatella)* or at least imitated somewhat *(Junta,* generally pronounced *ch-unta* for German ears). Stress patterns of the original language are usually ignored.

Comment: Well, *Vanille* ends either in -ille or in -illje when pronounced by Germans.

Comment: I agree with respect to the "uncommon letters", and it even leads to some hypercorrection, such as when *gnocchi* become "gno-tschi" instead of "(g)no-kki".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Oh yes, I totally forgot about `-illje`. Gnocchi is also a nice example of how it doesn't work (and how many Italians one knows xD)

Comment: My parents, who had to endure 7 years of obligatory Russian in school in the GDR, also do the Russian loanwords wrong. Boris Jelzin as in Boris Becker, for example.

Comment: Enschede is a typical trapword because the hyphenation when pronouncing it is Ens-che-de not En-sche-de. Archaic, like many location names. Gorinchem (pronounced as you would Gorkum) is another one.

Comment: Another one that is very far from the native Spanish pronunciation is "chorizo" (I have heard German speakers say [xoritso])

Answer (score 9):

Ich hoffe, dass es in Ordnung ist wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte. Es ist meine Muttersprache, und darin kann ich mich besser ausdrücken als auf Englisch. Auf Anfrage übersetzte ich meine Antwort jedoch auch gerne ins Englische.

Die Beobachtung, dass Deutschsprachige generell dazu tendieren, Wörter bestimmter Sprachen (Englisch, Französisch) wie in der Ursprungssprache auszusprechen, trifft nicht ganz zu.

**Michelin**
Der Markenname *Michelin* ist ein französisches Wort, und es wird in meiner Heimat Österreich auch französisch ausgesprochen: [miˈʃlɛ̃]. Als ich das erste Mal Fernsehwerbung aus Deutschland sah, wunderte ich mich sehr über die dort verwendete deutsche Aussprache [mɪçəˈlin]. In diesem Fall ist es also keineswegs so, dass es im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum dieselbe Aussprache für dasselbe Wort gibt.

**Colgate**
Dasselbe Phänomen erlebte ich beim Markennamen *Colgate*. Bei uns in Österreich hört man nur die originale englische Aussprache, während in Deutschland das Wort so ausgesprochen wird, als würde es sich auf *Beate* reimen.

**Puzzle**
Auch das ist ein englisches Wort, das in Österreich meist (jedoch nicht immer) wie »passl« (also englisch) ausgesprochen wird. In mehreren deutschen Fernsehshows hörte ich aber sowohl vom jeweiligen Moderator, als auch von Spielteilnehmern die Aussprache »putsle«, also eine deutsche Aussprache, und diese Variante wurde von niemandem korrigiert, scheint also in Deutschlang gängig zu sein.

**Donald Duck**
Hier ist es umgekehrt. Das englische Wort für *Ente*, *duck* wird natürlich mit einem spitzen a ausgesprochen: [dʌk]. Der Nachname der Comic-Figur Donald Duck wird aber in Österreich, vor allem von älteren Personen, wie der Imperativ von »ducken«, also mit u ausgesprochen: [duk]

**Tupperware**
Hier weiß ich nicht wie die Situation in Deutschland ist, aber in Österreich gibt es zwei Lager, die versuchen dem jeweils anderen Lagen die selbst für richtig gehaltene Aussprache beizubringen. Im Umlauf sind die deutsche Version [tʊpɐvaʁə] und die englische [tʌpəwæɹ]. Ich habe den Eindruck, dass beide Lager etwa gleich viele Anhänger haben.

**Douglas**
Auch der Name der Parfümerie-Kette Douglas führt zu einer ähnlichen Situation wie *Tupperware*: Die einen sprechen den Namen wie den Nachnamen des Schauspielers Michael Douglas, also [dʌɡləs], die anderen aber als [duglɑs]

---

**Tramway**
Das englische Wort für »Straßenbahn« wird - meiner Beobachtung nach - im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum wie ein deutsches Wort ausgesprochen [tʀamwai]. Die englische Aussprache [tʁamwɛ] habe ich hierzulande noch nie gehört.

**Jute**
Bei diesem englischen Wort hat die deutsche Aussprache [ˈjuːtə] die originale englische [ʤuːt] schon so sehr verdrängt, dass kaum noch jemandem bewusst ist, dass es sich hier um ein englisches Wort handelt.

---

Die hier angeführten Beispiele (ein französisches Wort, sonst lauter englische) belegen, dass es im deutschen Sprachraum weder eine einheitliche Aussprache für alle Fremd- und Lehnwörter aus verwandten bzw. benachbarten Sprachen gibt, noch dass generell alle englischen Wörter von einer Eindeutschung ausgenommen sind.

Den Grund dafür sehe ich darin, dass jene englischen Wörter, die bevorzugt deutsch ausgesprochen werden (Puzzle, Jute, Tramway und in Deutschland Colgate), zu einer Zeit in den deutschen Sprachraum einsickerten, als hier noch relativ wenige Menschen Englisch beherrschten.

Als dann Englisch ein Pflichtfach an deutschen und österreichischen Schulen wurde, stieg auch die Akzeptanz der englischen Aussprache. Gleichzeitig drangen immer mehr englische Wörter in den deutschsprachigen Alltag ein, die dann in ihrer englischen Aussprache übernommen wurden. In vielen Fällen wurde auch eine deutsche Aussprache gefunden, die zwar nicht ganz mit der originalen Aussprache übereinstimmt, ihr aber zumindest ähnlich ist. Es wird seit einigen Jahrzehnten also nicht mehr versucht, das geschriebene englische Wort so zu lesen als wäre es ein deutsches Wort (was in Österreich bei *Donald Duck*, in Deutschland bei *Colgate* und generell bei *Jute* durchaus der Fall ist).

Ich vermute, dass deutschsprachige Menschen Fremdwörter umso eher wie in der Originalsprache ausspreche, je mehr Menschen es gibt, die im deutschen Sprachraum diese Fremdsprache sprechen. Daher vermute ich, dass im Gebiet der ehemaligen DDR, wo lange Zeit an den Schulen Russisch ein Pflichtfach war, die Aussprache russischer Wörter eher wie in Russland klingt als das im Westen Deutschlands oder in Österreich der Fall ist.

Diese Hypothese würde auch erklären, warum die Chancen bei französischen und italienischen Wörtern relativ hoch sind, dass man sie wie in der Ursprungssprache ausspricht, während das beispielsweise bei Wörtern aus slawischen Sprachen nicht so sehr der Fall ist.

Comment: Eine Anekdote zu "Duck": In einem der Lustigen Taschenbücher gibt es den Werbespruch "Bankhaus Dagobert Duck - bedient Sie ruck-zuck!", so dass "Duck(en)" gewissermaßen sogar die "offizielle" Version ist.

Comment: Puzzle kenne ich nur als [/ˈpʊzl̩/].

Comment: Ich kenne zwar „Tram“, nicht aber „Tramway“. Gute Beobachtungen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Bei nachträglichen Recherchen habe ich festgestellt, dass »die Tramway« nur in Österreich gebräuchlich zu sein scheint, während man in Deutschland offenbar nur die Kurzform »die Tram« kennt. So gibt es in Wien und Graz jeweils ein Tramway-Museum und es gibt auch mehrere österreichische Internet-Seiten, die dem Thema »Tramway« gewidmet sind, aber nichts dergleichen in Deutschland. Dort schein man tatsächlich nur das Wort »Tram« zu kennen. *Der Tram* (männlich) ist in Österreich hingegen nur als Name für einen tragenden Holzbalken (z.B. in einer Zimmerdecke) in Verwendung.

Comment: @Veredomon: Aus meiner Kindheit (geboren 1965) kenne ich auch diesen Abzählreim: »Rucki zucki, Donald Ducki, Micky Mausi, eini außi«. (die beiden letzten Wörter sind Dialekt: eini = hinein; außi = hinaus) Auch hier reimt sich Ducki auf zucki. Und auch in diesem Lied von Ludwig Hirsch aus dem Jahr 1984 ist bei ca. 1:30 deutlich der Name »Dagobert Duck« mit einem u im Nachnamen zu hören: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdu81rOBUY8

Comment: Die Aussprache von *Colgate* haben sich wohl viele (zumindest auf alle Fälle ich) aus den Werbespots der Herstellerfirma angeeignet. Warum diese beschlossen haben, es eingedeutscht auszusprechen, weiß ich nicht. *Michelin* habe ich schon sowohl in der französischen wie in der eingedeutschten Aussprache gehört. Puzzle kommt definitiv aus einer Zeit, in der Eindeutschung noch die Norm war.

Comment: @dirkt: Zu Werbespots im Fernsehen ist anzumerken, dass sehr viele Spots, die in Deutschland produziert werden, neu synchronisiert werden bevor sie auch in Österreich ausgestrahlt werden. Manchmal werden auch kurze Szenen, die für Österreicher besonders deutsch klingen, einfach herausgeschnitten. So ist z.B. in der Milchschnitte-Werbung "Wandertag" der Teilsatz "sogar die Frau Schlüters" in der Österreich-Fassung herausgeschnitten, weil "Schlüters" ein Name ist, den man sofort mit Deutschland, aber niemals mit Österreich assoziiert.

Comment: Zu _Donald Duck_: Die Marketingleute bei Ehapa waren sich da auch untereinander nicht einig, denn es gab (vor über zwanzig Jahren) auch den (nicht besonders gelungenen) Werbespruch _Jeden Donners-Duck neu!_, bei dem _Duck_ für _Tag_ eintritt. – Zu _Colgate_ fällt mir _Maggi_ ein, das in der Schweiz mit italienischer Aussprache (_dsch_) verbreitet ist, in Deutschland aber mit deutschem _g_.

Comment: »Tupperware« wird in Deutschland fast nur deutsch ausgesprochen, und oft das »-ware« weggelassen. »Tupperdose« [tʊpɐdoːzə] , »Tupperparty« usw.

Comment: @ospalh: Ich würde ja vermuten, dass Letzteres eine Folge von Ersterem ist: Unter "Tupperware" verstehen in Deutschland viele intuitiv "die Ware der Firma Tupper", und somit erscheint der Zusatz "-ware" als optional und auslassbar. Das zeigt aber ein generelles Muster für mehrere Beispiele dieser Antwort auf: Bei Begriffen wie Michelin, Tupperware oder Colgate dürfte oftmals gar kein Bewusstsein vorhanden sein, dass es sich überhaupt um Fremdworte handelt. Erst in Fällen, in denen dieses Bewusstsein existiert, stellt sich die Frage, ob das Fremdwort auch seine originale Aussprache behält.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the answer really neither depends on how well a certain language is spoken in Germany nor the educational level. I rather think, it depends on the assumption, which languages should be spoken correctly with a high level of education.

English, French, Latin and old Greek all once were lingua franca in Europe. They are the general compass of old/new humanistic education in Germany. (Some deviations do occur: Russian in the GDR, Spanish now getting more and more popular, Italian among intellectuals and the self-perceived elite.) So, it is assumed, that one pronounces words from these languages at least partly correct. If one doesn't, one is easily corrected and tries better next time. Of course, this works best for the living languages English and French. For Latin, this is mostly reduced to grammar, e.g. the plurals of `Status, Malus, Bonus, Globus, …`. For Greek, this is reduced to stressing the third last syllable: `Sokrates, Analysis, Paradoxon`.

As this behaviour is not founded on actual knowledge of the language and country, just assumptions, overcorrecture is quite common. Just listen to the pronounciation of `Mallorca`. Many people pronounce it Castillan. If I do pronounce it Catalonian (the actual regional language), I get corrected.

Comment: Your answer makes me wonder what the Castillan and Catalonian pronounciations of `Mallorca` actually are … Note that there are enough people saying `Mallorca` (with a double l) or `Malle` (`Maje` as a short form is not heard) most often found in the not-so educated half of the population ;)

Comment: @Jan The pronounciation should be like in the English `million`.

Comment: so `/maljorka/`?

Comment: @Jan That's how I understand it.

Comment: @Jan: It’s actually a sound that exists neither in (at least British) English nor in German, a palatal lateral approximant written in IPA as [ʎ]. It is like a [l], but formed further back, at the position of the [ʝ] (which isn’t lateral nor an approximant), so it sounds like a blending of those two sounds to a German. It’s not the same as those two sounds pronounced after each other. – Since many Spanish speakers don’t make this distinction anymore ([yeísmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo)), the pronunciation with a plain [ʝ] can hardly be called wrong today; but [l] certainly is.

Comment: Bildung ist ein zweischneidiges Schwert. Um Loch Ness richtig auszusprechen, muß man entweder ungebildet oder _sehr_ gebildet sein; die in der Mitte machen es falsch. (Korrekt: Loch wie Dach, weil es Schottisch ist und nicht Englisch).

Answer (score 2):

The idea that German speakers try to pronounce words of foreign origin like the original seems to me essentially incorrect. It does not even work like that with a closely-related language like Swedish. You can bet that a German speaker would get all the following Swedish words and names wrongly pronounced:

- Gösta
- gylden
- Wilander
- Kerstin
- själ
- Göteborg
- kedja.

And it is even more difficult with languages like Bengali, say.

Comment: It does, when you compare English, French, Spanish, usw. speakers. I'm not. Anyway, that is what I meant in the origiinal post  as: **But, one easily finds counter-examples.** Yours --good to know-- is one counter-example more (which is outside my scope, since I don't know Swedish).

Comment: I think that’s based on the low percentage of Swedish speakers in Germany, which has a double effect: a) Most people don’t know how to pronounce Swedish names or words that they have read (noone would say _själ_ or _kedja_ in a German sentence, but _köttbullar_ has been loaned). b) Those few that know assume (correctly, in my experience) that they won’t be understood by the majority if they employed Swedish pronunciation.

Comment: @chirlu: Interestingly, a well-known Swedish furniture chain advertises köttbullar using the pronunciation [çøtbʊlaɐ] (or very similar), i.e., beginning with a *ch* as in *Licht.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Yes, that’s the Swedish pronunciation (approximately). But this chain also lets their presenter speak German with a Swedish accent.

Comment: (For anyone wondering, all the *g*s and *k*s in the examples above are pronounced [j] and [​ɕ​], respectively, all the *r*s are consonantic, the *d* in _gylden_ is mute (therefore nowadays usually spelt _gyllen_), *Wilander* is stressed on the second syllable, and *sj* indicates a sound similar to [ʃ]. Quantity of certain sounds and quality of vowels is also a bit off when compared to German. Depending on the origin of a particular Swedish speaker, the /rst/ cluster in _Kerstin_ and the /ʃ/ sound may be realized in a different way; not to speak of the tonal accent.)

Comment: @chirlu I contest the *sj* being [ʃ]. I have heard that that be North Swedish, while South Swedish uses a sound a lot closer to h … or take 27, which contains *sju*, and was described as ‘You just put far too hot food in your mouth. You now inhale and exhale to cool it and to say tjugosju’ ;)

Comment: @Jan: I wrote *a sound similar to [ʃ]* and then *Depending on the origin of a particular Swedish speaker, ... the /ʃ/ sound may be realized in a different way*. I do think that covers it. The point of my comment was not to describe the exact sounds, but in what ways the Swedish pronunciation deviates from what a naïve German speaker would think. I believe said naïve speaker would try something like [sj] instead of [ʃ].

Comment: @chirlu I’m hesitant to call the sound I heard ‘something similar to [ʃ]’. It’s something similar to [h] in my opinion, which is far away from [ʃ]. But I do admit of having missed the origin part.

Comment: @Jan: It's not a [h] (glottal fricative), that much is certain. :-) Apart from this, it is very complicated, not the least because there are many variations (not just a simple North/South distinction). English Wikipedia has a bit more about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sj-sound

Comment: @Jan  It is very true with the regional variation. For instance, in Värmland it is very much a [ʃ]-sound.

Comment: But any German would be totally convinced to get them all right! So they definitely _try_ but often it doesn't work.