# Why is the Sk digraph in "Skizzieren" [sk] pronounced different from the Sk in "Ski" [sh]?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

In the German language, K always produces the [k] sound in English words like "king" and S produces either the [s] sound, but often the [z] sound aswell especially when it is the first letter of a word (ex: Sonne) and also the [sh] sound when part of consonant clusters St and Sp (ex: Stock). If that's the case, why is the Sk in German word "Ski" pronounced "Shi" as opposed to "Skizzieren" pronounced "Ski-tsi-eren"? Why is K silent in the "Ski" unlike in "Skizzieren" when both words have the same digraph followed the same vowel?

Edit

So according to some research, the reason behind it is the origin of words: Ski and Skizzieren
The first one occurs from the Norwegian word "Ski" which is pronounced a lot like the "Sh" sound in Norwegian aswell. That's due to the fact that in Norwegian, K before I and Y sounds a lot like the "ch" in German "ich" so therefore, in Norwegian "Ski" is pronounced with an Sh sound and that word was borrowed into German. The latter comes from the Italian word "Schizzo" where the "Ch" is used for the hard [k] sound before I and E in Italian. So I understand the origin of the "Skizzieren" word but now the question comes, why isn't Ski spelled "Schi" when "Sch" makes the same sound but much less ambiguously?

Comment: K always produces the [k] sound in English, like in knight and knowledge?

Comment: Hi Akshat Goswami, and welcome to German.SE! It is quite cool that you found the answer to your question by own research. It is perfectly acceptable, actually it is even encouraged to answer your own questions here!

Comment: @user unknown: Read my sentence: "In the German language, K always produces the [k] sound in English words like "king"                                                                                      Yes in English, K is often silent especially when it comes before N in words like "knight", "knowledge", "doorknob", etc. In German, K is always [k] except in "ski" like words and other words that have been adopted from Norwegian where it might be making an "sh"  sound.

Answer (score 6):

You are right about the origins of the words: *schizzo* (pronounced "skitso") is an italian word and means "splash" or "splodge". The German "Skizze" just mimics how the word is originally pronounced. "Ski", on the other hand, is from the Norwegian "ski", which itself comes from Old Nordian "skið" (piece of wood, log). See also: Kluge, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache.

Speaking of Kluges book, in fact the lemma "Ski" just points to "Schi", which is an accepted form of writing it. Without having checked what the "Rechtschreibkommission" has to say about it I suppose both variants "Ski" and "Schi" are common.

Generally speaking integrating a word into the German language is a lengthy process and changes in writing and meaning take some time. "Skizze" is perhaps much longer used in German than "Ski/Schi" (Seebold, the current custodian of the aformentioned "Kluge", claims "Schi" is used since the 18th century).

You can see that with words like "Büro", which is derived from the French "bureau". When it was introduced into German it was written like the french word, over time the spelling changed and now mimicks the french pronounciation but using german spelling rules. The greek "φῶς" ("light", genitive "φωτός") from which "photo-" comes, was written like the English version, with a "ph" transliterating the greek "φ" (phi). Over time "ph" was replaced by "f". Now, "φῶς" is related to the verb "φαίνειν" (to make visible, to bring to light), from which words like "phenomenon" (German: "Phänomen"), but also "epiphany" (German: "Epiphanie") come. But the phi here was transliterated with "ph". The same with "Physik".

You see the process is not only lengthy, it is also inconsistent. Most Germans write "Mayonaise" but some insist on "Majonäse" and "Soße" in general instead of "Sauce".

After all being said and done, language is what people say and write. Grammar is just an afterthought, trying to categorize what was said and written before. All the committees trying to *pre*scribe (instead of *de*scribe) how language should be used and done ultimately have failed so far. So, the best answer for your question is probably to shrug with the shoulder.

Comment: "Schi" is not common and Duden doesn't recommend it.

Comment: @nobody I think "doesn't recommend it" is pretty much overstating the meaning of "alternative Schreibung". BTW: Duden doesn't "recommend" any words over others, it just lists them.

Comment: @tofro Duden online literally has a section "Von Duden empfohlene Schreibung"

Comment: @Nobody maybe you can simply tell us what Duden says about Ski/Schi. It's not so clear what you mean by "doesn't recommend it".

Comment: @JamesMartin https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ski Duden online is free. But what I wrote reflects very accurately what the Duden web page says. It recommends "Ski" and lists "Schi" as an alternative spelling.

Comment: @Nobody: "Schi" is very common in Austria and somewhat common in Bavaria

Comment: Regarding "bureaux": "-aux" is plural, the singular is "bureau" (fr)/"Bureau" (de, outdated). My personal feeling is that the plural "Bureaus" was more common in German than "Bureaux". ([Wiktionary lists both](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bureau).)

Comment: @Heinzi: you are right, that was a leftover from editing the text. I meant the singular. I corrected it.

Comment: @Nobody: you may notice that the Duden is no authority any more (since 1996, to be precise). Furthermore, I have not recommended, suggested or otherwise commented on anything, I just reported on the usage.

Comment: Would most Germans not write _Mayonnaise_ (with two n’s), rather than _Mayonaise_? Also, I have seen edh miswritten as _đ_ before, but _ᵭ_ with a tilde through the ascender is a first for me! The correct form is of course _ð_, so _skíð_.

Answer (score 2):

Everything has been correctly said about why *Ski* is pronounced with a *sh* (English) or *sch* (German) sound while *skizzieren* is pronounced /sk/. This leaves the question on the spelling of the word (*Ski* versus *Schi*).

As has been asked [and answered](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22483/15318) elsewhere on this site, German generally tends to keep the foreign spelling of loan words while their pronunciation is adapted to German phonology in varying degrees. Therefore, it makes sense that the loanword *Ski* retains its Norwegian spelling.

Rarely, the spelling of loanwords is adapted to German conventions. Examples of this are *platzieren* (derived from French *placer*, used to be spelt *placieren*) or *Fotograf*. The 1996 reform suggested a larger number of these adapted German spelling, especially for words that are no longer generally recognised as loanwords. *Ski* would be one of those words, so spelling it *Schi* would make sense.

And, in actual fact, it is spelt *Schi* … in Austria. As an avid skier, former skiing instructor and a long time ago student of a skiing school, I got to see a variety of skiing places near my home in southern Bavaria (50-ish km from Austria), Austria and, to a lesser extent, South Tyrol. I have not yet come across any place in Bavaria (or elsewhere in Germany) that wrote the word as *Schi*. On the other hand, I do not recall ever having seen *Ski* in Austria (but I am less certain about that).

I have not been skiing or to wintersport regions in Switzerland so I cannot comment on Swiss German usage. I have not been in South Tyrol enough to be certain whether they prefer *Ski* or *Schi*. However, Austria generally overwhelmingly prefers *Schi*. And Germany practically exclusively uses *Ski*.

An Austrian would most likely write:

> Ich kaufe meinen Schipass an der Kassa.

Meanwhile, a German would write:

> Ich kaufe meinen Skipass an der Kasse.

Answer (score 1):

You found the answer yourself. In German we often retain both the original spelling **and** the original pronounciation of loanwords. Over time the spelling is changed to reflect the pronounciation with German spelling rules.

Skizze had been loaned from Italian way earlier than Ski had been loaned from Norwegian. Skiing is only popular since the beginning of the 20th century in Germany.